# How to use non-ASCII character extracted from an XML file in PyGTK?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, gtk, pygtk

I am using Python-GTK and I would like to use the permille character - which looks like ‰ o/oo - in a GTK entry. GTK uses Unicode, or more precisely UTF-8.

What I actually do is read the strings from an XML this way:

```py
self.xdb = ElementTree.parse("myfile.xml")
xmap = self.xdb.getiterator(tag="map") 
for x in xmap:
    unit = x.get("unit","")
```

The XML file is written this way:

```xml
<map idx='398' unit='\u2030' />
```

Then I convert the strings (in this case '\u2030') in Unicode this way:

```py
 unistring = ""
    for s in unit:
         unistring += unichr(ord(s))
```

And afterwards I set the text of the gtk-entry with the converted string:

```py
entry.set_text(unistring)
```

But the text in the entry shows '\u2030' instead of the expected character.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: **Neither** of "\x89" or "\u137" is U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN...

Comment: Thanks, changed that. However still shows the string \u2030 in the entry ...

Comment: `'\u2030'` is 6 characters long, not 1. Did you mean to use `u'\u2030'` instead?

Comment: Actually, I'm reading the string from an xml file, so I'm not allowed to add the 'u' in front of the string :-(

Comment: How is it written in the file? How are you reading it?

Comment: I'm using ElementTree.. I just edited the question with more details

Comment: I found a workaround : write 'promille' in the xml and in the code: `if unit=='promille': unit = u'\u2030'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<map idx='398' unit='\u2030' />
```

`\u` escapes are used in Python string literals, not in XML. The XML file should use the raw character itself:

```
<map idx='398' unit='‰' />
```

If you really can't support direct non-ASCII characters in your editor or whatever else is producing the file, you can use character references:

```
<map idx='398' unit='&#x2030;' />
```